# Access return value from event Listener callback function from main program?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which contains an input field and a submit button. The whole program depends on the submission of the form to continue. Each function can only perform one task as follows:

- Get input value
- Output the value

```js
allEvents();

//output(name)

function allEvents(){
  document.getElementById('formOne').addEventListener('submit',getInputValue)
}
 
function getInputValue(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let name = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  return name;
}

function output(n){
  console.log(n)
}
```

```html
<form id="formOne">
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <input type="submit" id = "inputText">
</form>
```

How do I access the value of name after the form has submitted in the main program, so that I can pass it to function `output()`.

**Note:** Function inputText() can only return the input name.

Comment: You'd have to do `output(name)` from inside `getInputValue()` because you cannot otherwise access a local variable from outside a function.

Comment: @Pointy I want each function to perform different tasks

Comment: @yuvrajprogrammer Think carefully, where exactly is the return value from `getInputvalue` going to?

Comment: `There are different functions to perform different tasks:`, could you expand on what you mean here?

Comment: The function getInputValue must return the value of input field only. The output must be handled by another function

Comment: Tell me which function/variable in your code receives the return value from `getInputValue` function.

Comment: @Teemu I need to use the return value in the output() function from the main program

Comment: Maybe, but tell me where it is actually received? A tip: the caller of a function receives the return value. Which exact function in your code calls `getInputvalue` function?

Comment: @Teemu I do not know where it is being received

Comment: OK, now to the point: It is received in the native code `addEventListener` executes, there's no way you could use the returned value from an event listener's callback.

Comment: @Teemu Then, how do I use the return value in the main program without global assignment? Do I need to restructure my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated that you want each `function` to do different things. This is a good idea, but then take a look at this function:

```
function getInputValue(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let name = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  return name;
}
```

Is this getting the input value only? Nope, it is preventing the default behavior of `e` as well. But you will want to get the input value later as well. This is not only getting the value, but setting it as well. Now, first things first, let's define a prototype for this purpose.

```
function InputOutput() {
    var inputs = {}; //This will contain key-value pairs.

    this.setInputValue = function(name, val) {
        inputs[name] = val;
    };

    this.getInputValue(name) {
        return inputs[name];
    }

    this.getNames() {
        var result = [];
        for (var key in inputs) result.push(key);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, lets instantiate this and use it:

```
//output(name)

function allEvents(){
  document.getElementById('formOne').addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //Are you sure you do not want to execute the submit?
      let tag = document.getElementById('inputText');
      let name = tag.name;
      let value = tag.value;
      inputOutput.setInputValue(name, value);
  });
}

var inputOutput = new InputOutput();
allEvents();
```

and later you can get the names by using `getNames`, like this:

```
function output(name) {
    consolge.log(inputOutput.getInputValue(name));
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
output(inputOutput.getNames()[0]);
```

EDIT

Of course you can avoid the usage of global variables, by wrapping a lot of things into a `function` which will be the value of `onload` of your `body` tag, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Because `getInputValue()` returns the name, you can pass it directly to `output(name)` .

```
allEvents();

function allEvents(){
document.getElementById('formOne').addEventListener('submit',output(getInputValue))
}

function getInputValue(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let name = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  return name;
}

function output(n){
  console.log(n)
}
```

Comment: Is callback function the only possible solution in this case?

Comment: This sets `undefined` to listen the submission. However, `undefined` is deaf, it can't hear the call.

Comment: What if I have several functions that depend on getInputValue()?

Comment: If you need to use the return from `getInputValue()` in diferent places you will have to store the returned value on a variable and pass the variable to the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare the variable `name` outside of the function scope.

```
let name

function allEvents(){
  document.getElementById('formOne').addEventListener('submit',getInputValue)
}

function getInputValue(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  name = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  return name;
}

function output(n){
  console.log(n)
}

output(name)
```

However, why not just call your `output` function from within your `getInputValue` value?

```
function allEvents(){
  document.getElementById('formOne').addEventListener('submit',getInputValue)
}

function output(n){
  console.log(n)
}

function getInputValue(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let name = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  output(name)
  return name;
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid global variable. And I want each function to do something unique

Comment: i dont think you know what you mean when you're saying "do something unique"

Comment: Basically, the first function can only return the input name and nothing else

Comment: well how is return supposed to be used if you dont want to use callbacks?
It will return into nothing if you won't implement some subsequent action.

That `getInputValue` just happens once you click the button. You specifying global variable is the only option to retain value

Comment: Is callback the only possible solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Jiminy Cricket.  Reading through all of this "stuff", I couldn't decide which was more messed-up.  The question, or the answers !

Looking at the Question:

```
function allEvents(){
 document.getElementById('formOne').addEventListener('submit',getInputValue)
}
```

Why would anyone be adding an `Event Listener` to `formOne` ?  What does the form have to do with anything ?  It's useless.

And continuing with the Question,

```
function getInputValue(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  let name = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  return name;
}
```

Why would anyone be getting an `Element by ID` of `inputText` ?  Seriously.  What does that have to do with anything ?  That is essentially the "Submit" button.  You aren't going to find anyone's name in the interior of a button.

And then there was the Note that he added underneath his question ... Sorry, but there is no Function called `inputText()`.

And now for the first Answer ( the one that has 2 up-votes ); Is that supposed to be JavaScript ?  I typed it in, and it doesn't run.  It basically has an error on every line.

And for the second answer ( with one up-vote ), I typed that one in too.  It doesn't run either.

I hope the original poster is willing to make a modification to his HTML.  Because I tried running his code in Internet Explorer and Chrome, and they don't treat his HTML structure the same, because his "Submit" button does not include the `value` attribute.  So each Browser has to take a guess about what value to insert.

So if he will scrap his "pseudo-Submit" button, and replace it with a real Submit button :

```
<button type="submit" id="inputText">Submit</button>
```

And also, allow me to add an HTML paragraph tag to print the results in, because I think `console.log` ought to be banned.

```
<p id="outputIDname" ></p>
```

Then here is some code that actually runs.  ( And I have also included the `console.log` statements for the people who need it. )

```
allEvents( ) ; 

// output(name)


function allEvents( ) { 
    document.querySelector( "#inputText" ).addEventListener( "click", output ) ; 
} 


function output( e ) { 
    e.preventDefault() ; 
    let tempName = getInputValue( ) ; 
    console.log( "name Inside of Output Function = " + tempName ) ; 
    document.querySelector( "#outputIDname" ).innerHTML = tempName ; 
} 


function getInputValue(  ) { 
    let name = document.getElementById( 'name' ).value ; 
    console.log( "name Inside of Input Function = " + name ) ; 
    return name ; 
}
```

Here is the modified HTML :

```
<form id="formOne">
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <button type="submit" id="inputText">Submit</button>
</form>

<p id="outputIDname" ></p>
```

Here is the output:

```
// name Inside of Input Function = John
// name Inside of Output Function = John

// And the here is the output that is printed inside of the
// Paragraph Tag that I added to his HTML structure:

// John
```

And if you want to see just how much the Browsers hated his "Submit" button, just try replacing my "Submit" button with the one that he had.  The Java Script will no longer work.

And one final note:  Internet Explorer is so dumb, that ( if you replace my "Submit" button with the one that he had ), Internet Explorer doesn't even realize that the Java Script is not working.  If you look in console.log, you will see that Internet Explorer just happily prints out 'John' and 'John', as if there is nothing wrong.  But the Paragraph Tag ( that I added to the page ) remains empty.  Just one of many reasons to ban console.log